# Unsafe assignment of an `any` value. for custom hook function

Tags: typescript

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {
  return useContext(MyContext);
};

export const useCustomManager = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const clearThings = () => {
      setThings([]);
  };

  return {
    clearMessages,
  };
};


// When I try to use it, I get: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.
const { clearThings } = useCustomHook();
```

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and I'm not really sure how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not absolutely clear from your code what type of `MyContext` is. The general problem is it's not detailed enough for typescript to guess the type of `useCustomHook` result. To make it work you just have either to provide a stub context or to explicitly type context value:

```ts
const MyContext = React.createContext({ clearMessages: () => {} })
// or
const MyContext = React.createContext<{ clearMessages: () => void }>(context)
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/ND5xjm)